# RegEx for removing single and multi lines of comments & spaces except for hints

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, regex-group

How to extract Plsql code by removing single and multiple lines of comments & leading / trailing spaces but not remove Oracle hints?

Actually I want to extract the DDL of a view and add new column into the views 
and rebuild the view dynamically. But some of views are  very complex (big size) and have many spaces, single line comments, multiple line comments and hints..

```
select text 
from All_views
where owner = 'Schema_name'
  and view_name = 'View1';
```

I inititally thought to apply Oracle regular expression but it's removing hints as well.

Can anybody please guide me on how to achieve this?

USER want to keep this comment line post adding the new field into the views.
Since it's very much imp for them for auditing purpose.

My view syntax:

```
Select /*+LEADING  ACL VS TXN  ACT TTY SEC SECID SHR_UDF*/ 
                        TXN_ID,
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP1 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP2 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP3 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP4 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP5 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP6 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP7 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP8 TABLENAME****/
                        /****SELECT * FROM  ALL_TAB_COLUMN****/
                        /****  wHERE COLUMN_NAME=COL2****/
                        /****  gROUP BY TABLE_NAME***/
                        /****  oRDER BY1****/
                        /* CHANGE  JIRA1234 STARTS*/
                        ACL.aCCOUNT_NUMBER,
                        /* CHANGE  JIRA1234 ENDS*/
                        TXN.  TXN_SALE_dATE,
                        TXN.TXN_iNVOICE_DATE,
                        TXN.  TXN_pUBLISH_DATE,
                        ACL.TXN_EXCH_DATE,
                        ACL.SALES_DATE,
                        ACL.pRICE_DATE,
                        --ACL.LAST_UPDATED,
                        TTY.TTY_TTY_TYPE_ID,
                        /* CHANGE  JIRA7890 STARTS*/
                        TXN.ACL_OPEM_ENTRY_NO,
                        /* CHANGE  JIRA7890 eNDS*/
                        FROM  SCHEMA.aCCOUNT_MASTER  ACL
                        JOIN  SCHEMA.TXN_MASTER TXN
                        ON ACL.BRANCH_CD=TXN.BRANCH_CD
                        AND ACL.aCCOUNT_NO=TXN.aCCOUNT_NO
                        JOIN SCHEMA.TXN_TYPE_MASTER  TTY
                        ON  TXN.TTY_TYPE_ID=TTY.TTY_TYPE_ID
                        AND  TTY.SCE_ID=TXN_SEC_ID';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear Expert, Please show some lights on this problem...Many many thanks in advace!!! My DB version is Oracle 11G R2..

Comment: Hi Emma,  Please have a look on the  Proc,i want to add field in view dynamicallly

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not all that clear but I will have a go at answering the first bit "How to extract Plsql code by removing single and multiple lines of comments & leading / trailing spaces but not remove Oracle hints?"

I think you were on the right path with using a regex, the below will remove all the comments without removing the hint.

```
select  regexp_replace('Create Or Replace Force view Schema_name.View1 as
                        Select /*+LEADING  ACL VS TXN  ACT TTY SEC SECID SHR_UDF*/ 
                        TXN_ID,
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP1 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP2 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP3 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP4 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP5 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP6 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP7 TABLE NAME****/
                        /****  IF  YOU ADD COL CHECK OUT THE TEMP8 TABLENAME****/
                        /****SELECT * FROM  ALL_TAB_COLUMN****/
                        /****  wHERE COLUMN_NAME=COL2****/
                        /****  gROUP BY TABLE_NAME***/
                        /****  oRDER BY1****/
                        /* CHANGE  JIRA1234 STARTS*/
                        ACL.aCCOUNT_NUMBER,
                        /* CHANGE  JIRA1234 ENDS*/
                        TXN.  TXN_SALE_dATE,
                        TXN.TXN_iNVOICE_DATE,
                        TXN.  TXN_pUBLISH_DATE,
                        ACL.TXN_EXCH_DATE,
                        ACL.SALES_DATE,
                        ACL.pRICE_DATE,
                        --ACL.LAST_UPDATED,
                        TTY.TTY_TTY_TYPE_ID,
                        /* CHANGE  JIRA7890 STARTS*/
                        TXN.ACL_OPEM_ENTRY_NO,
                        /* CHANGE  JIRA7890 eNDS*/
                        FROM  SCHEMA.aCCOUNT_MASTER  ACL
                        JOIN  SCHEMA.TXN_MASTER TXN
                        ON ACL.BRANCH_CD=TXN.BRANCH_CD
                        AND ACL.aCCOUNT_NO=TXN.aCCOUNT_NO
                        JOIN SCHEMA.TXN_TYPE_MASTER  TTY
                        ON  TXN.TTY_TYPE_ID=TTY.TTY_TYPE_ID
                        AND  TTY.SCE_ID=TXN_SEC_ID', '/\*\*.+\*\*/\s+|/\*\s.+\*/\s+|--.+\s+', '', 1, 0) from dual;
```

Output is

```
Create Or Replace Force view Schema_name.View1 
as 
Select /*+LEADING  ACL VS TXN  ACT TTY SEC SECID SHR_UDF*/ TXN_ID, 
ACL.aCCOUNT_NUMBER, 
TXN.  TXN_SALE_dATE, 
TXN.TXN_iNVOICE_DATE, 
TXN.  TXN_pUBLISH_DATE, 
ACL.TXN_EXCH_DATE, 
ACL.SALES_DATE, 
ACL.pRICE_DATE, 
TTY.TTY_TTY_TYPE_ID, 
TXN.ACL_OPEM_ENTRY_NO, 
FROM  SCHEMA.aCCOUNT_MASTER  ACL 
JOIN  SCHEMA.TXN_MASTER TXN 
ON ACL.BRANCH_CD=TXN.BRANCH_CD 
AND ACL.aCCOUNT_NO=TXN.aCCOUNT_NO 
JOIN SCHEMA.TXN_TYPE_MASTER  TTY 
ON  TXN.TTY_TYPE_ID=TTY.TTY_TYPE_ID 
AND  TTY.SCE_ID=TXN_SEC_ID
```

Comment: Many thanks Shaun for your helps.. I try to impliment like this and its  it works fine...But Cleints wonot accept it  since all the comment line  which was used for auditing purpose was remove now...IS there any way to  add again those comment line..

Comment: Requirement is like this.
=========================
I want to Modfiy the DDL  of View dynamically .Assume  my  Views is haveing 10 columns.
user have  added 5 more field in base table along with datatype,Since views are created  previously  based on old column.
Now user want to add same 5 fields in views as well dynamically,where  i  face this  comment line issue.

Comment: As  mentioned by you I create a stored proc  and try to implement like this and its it seems to be fine..But my Client won't accept it ,since all the comment line which was used for auditing purpose is removed now...
IS there any way to split the view definition ,add required column,and add again those comment line and finally Rebuild view along with new column. Thank you..

Comment: Kindly have a look on my newly added  proc  and advice  how to implement as described over.

Comment: The only reason I can see to remove comments is to get round the issue of the FROM in the comments..... You would be better to just leave the comments there and change your INSTR to find the last instance of FROM rather than the first (use -1 as the starting position in your instr).  That way you don't need to remove and re-add the comments.

Comment: Thank you Shaun,I got it.:):)